# Wordpress - One particular .png is not appearing on page, others appear normally

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am developing a site in Wordpress. I am using a transparent .png image for the site logo, floating it over the header and navbar. Locally, everything worked fine. But once I uploaded the theme to a live site (hosted by GoDaddy), the logo disappeared. I am using a child of Twenty Thirteen, and placed the logo over the header and nav bar by floating it in the header.php file on a div tag.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
<a class="home-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
<h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
<h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
</a>
<div id="logo"></div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#logo {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
bottom: 0;
left: 30px;
width: 203px;
height: 201px;
background: transparent url(images/dcm_logo.png) bottom right no-repeat;
z-index:1000;
```

No image appears. However, when I mouse over the area where it should be, I get a change in content in the status bar at the bottom of the browser. It's like the image SHOULD be there, but its invisible. I tried putting other images in its place in the CSS (just dropping other image names in that were in the folder with it, not changing the file path) and the images showed normally, even .png transparencies. I have verified that the logo images are true .pngs, and not misnamed Photoshop files or something like that.

I'd like to emphasize the point that this all worked when I hosted the site locally via xampp, and this problem did not manifest until I moved everything to GoDaddy. All other images work normally.

Can anyone help me sort this out? Thanks

Comment: Normally these issues appears when your image path is not properly defined.
Can you post the URL of your website..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with image links. Try `url(/images/dcm_logo.png)` or `url(../images/dcm_logo.png)`. See if the image appears. Check also if the file name is spelled correctly. Have you tried to load image on servers again?

Comment: I checked this, the image didnt appear after using both of the above variations. The /images folder is in the same folder as index.php and home.php. Is it possible that since this is a test domain (and therefore not in the root but in a subfolder), the index.php reference is trying to generate in a different folder, like the root folder on the website?

Comment: If so, try using `url(/yourfoldername/images/dcm_logo.png)`. In theory, the `url(/ images / dcm_logo.png)` tells to look in the root folder for another folder called **images** where the file **dcm_logo.png** should be.